# Extjs Grid - callback store variable into pagingtoolbar

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1

I init store variable in 'initComponent' of gridpanel like

```
    initComponent: function() {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'MyDataObject',
            pageSize:_end,
            proxy: {
                 type: 'ajax',
                 url: myurl,
                 reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    totalProperty: 'total', // total data, see json output
                    root: 'results'    // see json output                   
                 }
             }
        });
        this.store = store;
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.store.load({params:{start:_star, limit:_end}
    });
```

I call store in pagingtoolbar like

```
dockedItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            store: this.store,
            pageSize: _end,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying results {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: 'No results'
        }
]
```

In my gridpanel still have data but my bottom show "no results" like
[image]

I think problem is **store: this.store,**. How can i make it work thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution in here **[Remote paging grid in extjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338707/remote-paging-grid-in-extjs?rq=1)**
and the code must like:

```
        this.store = store;
        this.dockedItems = [{
           xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
           store: this.store,
           displayMsg: 'Displaying results {0} - {1} of {2}',
           emptyMsg: 'No results',
           dock: 'bottom',
           displayInfo: true,
           pageSize: 22
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.store.load({params:{start:0, limit:22}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a store like this

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyDataStore', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        model: 'MyDataObject',
        storeId: 'myStoreId',
        pageSize:_end,
        proxy: {
             type: 'ajax',
             url: myurl,
             reader: {
                type: 'json',
                totalProperty: 'total', // total data, see json output
                root: 'results'    // see json output                   
             }
         }
    });
```

and then assign the myStoreId to the store-config of both the grid panel and the pagingtoolbar and the framework (the StoreManager) should create a single store which is assigned to both.

You can then either set autoload=true on your store or create a new store in initComponent of your grid and there do the loading manually.

Answer (score 0):

I met this stranger problem yesterday,before I fixed this problem ,I guess the status were not synchronization of stores in both grid and pagingbar ,I spent a long to debug this problem with Firebug ,in other words the stores are not the same one ,they just the same instance of a store ,so you can fix this problem in two ways,the first is create a global variable of store,both them could share it the second is use bindStore  method.for example support you have grid extension likes below

```
this.on('afterrender',function(){//this  is grid itself
        this.getBottomToolbar().bindStore(this.store)//set store of paggingtoolbar
    },this);
```